# Node.js zlib gzip buffer as "file" inside of archive

Tags: node.js, buffer, gzip, zlib, docker

I want to gzip a utf-8 buffer in node.js as a "file" inside of a gzip archive. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on the zlib page about how to do this and no insight here on stack overflow from what I have found so far. In the end, I don't actually want to write a file to the filesystem but rather just send the data as an HTTP request. If anyone has any idea how to accomplish this (whether zlib supports it already or if there is a package out there to do this) that would be a great help!

Just to clear up what this is for, this is to send a Dockerfile (in string form) over HTTP to a docker instance for the build image command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "gzip archive".  The gzip format stores only a single stream or file.  Do you mean the gzipped tar format (.tar.gz)?

zlib certainly supports writing gzip streams in memory.  With the `deflateInit2()` `windowBits` argument, you can request the gzip format.  See [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html).

I have not used node.js, so I don't know what front to zlib it presents.